# Taking in a list of arbitrary generics in a method using dynamic

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

Let's say I have an method:

```
public void update(List<InputSource<dynamic>> inputs);
```

InputSource is my own generic class.  Ideally, I want the List to be a list of InputSources of any instance of the generic.  Is this doable?  In other words, I want inputs to be able to hold an `InputSource<double>`, an `InputSource<string>`, and an `InputSource<int>` all in the same instance.

I tried this, but then I tried to use the method:

```
InputSource<double> ip = new InputSource<double>();

List<InputSource<dynamic>> inputSources = new List<InputSource<dynamic>>(){ip}; //THIS LINE GIVES ME A COMPILE TIME ERROR

update(inputSources);
```

The labeled line gives me a compiletime error:

```
Error   6   The best overloaded Add method 'System.Collections.Generic.List<InputSource<dynamic>>.Add(InputSource<dynamic>)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments  
Cannot convert from 'InputSource<double>' to 'InputSource<dynamic>'
```

Trying to add an explicit cast:

```
List<InputSource<dynamic>> inputSources = new List<InputSource<dynamic>>(){(InputSource<dynamic>)inputSource};
```

gives the following error:

```
Error   6   Cannot convert type 'InputSource<double>' to 'InputSource<dynamic>'
```

What is the correct way to achieve my goal here?

Comment: How about writing `update` method as `public void update<T>(List<InputSource<T>> inputs)`

Comment: What is `InputSource`?

Comment: @EZI that might work better for some simple cases, but it still wouldn't allow a list of heterogeneous types like those mentioned for double, string, and int.

Comment: Why not use List<dynamic>? Otherwise covariant and contravariant interfaces might be an alternative.

Comment: Just because you can cast `double` to `dynamic` **does not** mean you can cast `InputSource<double>` to `InputSource<dynamic>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can change your code like this,all `InputSource` based on `IInputSource`

```
public interface IInputSource
{ 
}
public class InputSource<T> : IInputSource
{
}

public void update(IList<IInputSource> inputs)
{
    IInputSource ip = new InputSource<double>();
    inputs.Add(ip);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest answer here.  I am accepting it for posterity but I feel like there must be an even more canonical answer, so I'd like to see other responses too.

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of the `update()` method using generics with some constraints

```
public void update<T>(List<InputSource<T>> inputs) where T: 
    IComparable,
    IComparable<T>,
    IConvertible,
    IEquatable<T>

// Check the T for safe if you want
```

Comment: It seems to me very strange to parameterize a method with a generic in a non-generic class.  Can you explain what's going on here and what the rationale is?

Answer (score 0):

Your compile error is not related to the `update()` method, there is error when you call the `Add()` method:

```
List<InputSource<dynamic>> inputSourceList = new List<InputSource<dynamic>>();
InputSource<double> ipDouble = new InputSource<double>();
inputSourceList.Add(ipDouble); // illegal
```

Even casting a `InputSource<double>` to `InputSource<dynamic>` is illegal, no matter `InputSource` is covariant or contravariant, because these variance does not apply to value type (for someone interested, you may try to compile `IEnumerable<object> objs = new List<double>()`):

```
InputSource<dynamic> ipDynamic = ipDouble; // illegal
```

You may use `List<dynamic>` or `List<object>` instead of `List<InputSource<dynamic>>` for storing a list of different objects.

Comment: Of course I can always use object, but then I run into a type-safety issue that objects of type non-InputSource<> can be passed in and this code will compile and run, leading to potential run-time exceptions; so I don't think this is a safe answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of Sky Fang's answer that you might like better.  Use an abstract class InputSource instead of IInputSource and derive InputSource from that.  Then you can do something like the following:

```
public
abstract    class   InputSource
{ 

    public      InputSource<T>  As<T>()     { return (InputSource<T>) this; }

    protected
    abstract    Object          getValue();

    public      Object          GetValue()  { return this.getValue(); }

}

public      class   InputSource<T> : InputSource
{

    public
    override    object  getValue()  { return this.GetValue(); }

    public
    new         T       GetValue()  { /* todo: do something interesting here */ throw new NotImplementedException(); }

}

public void update(IList<InputSource> inputs)
{
    inputs.Add(new InputSource<double>());
    inputs.Add(new InputSource<int>());
}
```

With an interface, everything is public.  With the abstract class, you can define protected abstract methods and properties, that you override in the generic subclass.  You can create methods that are not type safe in the abstract class, and then hide them with type safe equivalents in the generic subclass (like the GetValue method in this example).

And if you still want to use the IInputSource interface, you can have the abstract class implement that.